# Node.js https.request not grabbing entire site

Tags: node.js

I've been using request (npm install request) to grab HTML from webpages using the following code:

```
request("https://www.futbin.com" + "/17/player/3", function(error, response, full) {
    console.log(full);
});
```

Before today this worked perfectly. Now everytime I run this request it cuts off exactly before the data I actually want

Last lines of output: http://puu.sh/sKdU9/a93cd8fbcd.png
Relevant part of website (highlighted is what I want to grab): http://puu.sh/sKdW4/c7d87ec682.png

When pushing this to Heroku however the request works perfectly by itself. When run in my application however which before today worked perfectly, it does the same thing and cuts off right before the picture HTML.

I've also tried without the request library using the following code:

```
var https = require('https');

var options = {
  host: 'www.futbin.com',
  path: '/17/player/3',
};

callback = function(response) {
  var str = ''
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
  });
}

var req = https.request(options, callback);
req.end();
```

Exactly the same thing happens.

No errors are being thrown, it's always null.

Summary:

My PC request only: cuts off before picture
My PC full application: cuts off before picture
Heroku request only: success
Heroku full application: cuts off before picture

What would cause a request to just stop like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be an ssl related problem. If you try to load the site with curl you get the same issue. Curl will stop at the same line in the html code and complain about a tls error. But it will load fine if you transfer the site with gzip compression turned on.